# Gulp stream inside a for loop not working properly

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, gulp-concat

I have a gulp task similar to the following. I am trying to loop through and append a string to the page and also concatenate a corresponding file.

```
gulp.task('loop', function() {

    for(i =0; i < 10; i++) {

        gulp.src('./build/ross/templates/pages/_page_home.liquid')
            .pipe(plugins.insert.append('Loop ' + i))
            // real example has concat here
            .pipe(plugins.addSrc('./src/page/_page' + i + '.liquid'))
            .pipe(plugins.concat('_page_home.liquid'))
            .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/ross/templates/pages/'));

    }

});
```

Expected output would be something like

```
Loop 1
// _page1.liquid contents
Loop 2
// _page2.liquid contents
Loop 3
// _page3.liquid contents
and so on...
```

Actual output appears more like

```
// Original Page Contents here
Loop 9
// _page9.liquid contents
```

I did a `fs.readFile` on the original file in the loop and outputted the data and it is only outputting the original page contents and not the concatenated file or the string I'm trying to append.

I also did a `console.log(i)` inside and it's showing the proper numbers `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9`. I wonder if this has something to do with the gulp.src()

Update: Sometimes it appears that the output contents will actually have parts of the _page#.liquid contents. It is a bit inconsistent.

Is there a better way to do this with gulp or am I just doing something wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Comment: If I `console.log(i)` it will output  0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 etc...

Comment: inside your gulp-pipes you are asynchronous! your loop itself is NOT asynchronous. put the stuff in your loop inside a function and call that from inside your loop (with `i` as argument), and you will see it will work!

Comment: I am still getting the same issues, how can I tell one stream to finish before doing anything else?

Comment: Got it to work using `stream-to-promise` and `bluebird`  -- see https://gist.github.com/rdallaire/e84a796a09e2aa189534

Comment: now i got what you wanted to achieve. nice workaround...

Comment: Thanks hereandnow78!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it to work with some help from the people at #gulpjs on freenode irc.

This uses `stream-to-promise` and `bluebird`

```
var s2p = require('stream-to-promise');
var Promise = require('bluebird');

gulp.task('loop2', function() {
    // don't forget your `var`s!
    var buildIt = function(i){
        return gulp.src('./build/ross/templates/pages/_page_home.liquid')
            .pipe(plugins.insert.append('Loop ' + i))
            .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/ross/templates/pages/'))
            .on('end', function(){ console.log(i + ' -- done')});
    }

    var indexes = [];

    for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        indexes.push(i);
    }

    // // sequence them
    indexes.reduce(function(p, index){
        return p.then(function(){
            return s2p(buildIt(index));
        });
    }, Promise.resolve());

});
```